# Difference between Google mobile Ads and Google Admob

Tags: android, sdk, admob

I'm trying to implement ads in my application . I have two choices Google mobile Ads or Google Admob . Can someone tell me the major differences between them ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both are same, but Google has announced deprecation of Android Google AdMob SDK

The new library Google mobile Ads has full support for the Android Advertising ID, and is compliant with the latest Google Play Ad Policy.

Refer [Link](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2014/02/since-joining-google-play-services-back.html)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think these are two separate thing !! They are the same concept. Maybe you are refering the different sdk versions but what i know is the curren sdk name is admob.

You are refering to one thing and thats the service google provides that you can earn money helping google advertise through your app.

And beside that, you can find what your users are like and find great information and statistics about their activities and their interests.

Comment: But both have different gradle dependencies ,right ?

Comment: Yes they are both one concept. Maybe you are refering to the different versions of their sdk. The new one is admob

Comment: "AdMob" is the former name of the standalone SDK (came in the form of a JAR).  The new SDK is named "Mobile Ads SDK", and it ships with Google Play services.  AdMob has been deprecated, so you will be using the Google Play services dependency in your Gradle.